# onClick event in a for loop (Swift) not working

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, segue, xcode9

Data sharing between two view controllers by using segue is not working in for loop. I am using Xcode9 and Swift

### swift4

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var distnames = [String]()
var distcodes = [String]()
var data1: [AnyObject] = []
var values = [String]()
var values1 = [String]()
var current_arr :[String] = []
var ofcnames = " ";
var ofccodes = " ";
var code = " ";

var testtext = "";
var id = "";
var tiTle = "";
var releaseYear = "";

@IBOutlet weak var Verticalstackview: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var testlabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("code is \(code)")
    self.values = [String]()
    self.values1 = [String]()
    self.ofcnames = "";
    self.ofccodes = "";

    Alamofire.request("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")

        .responseJSON { (response) in
            if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let jsondata = JSON(response.result.value!)
                // print(jsondata)
                if let da = jsondata["movies"].arrayObject
                {
                    self.data1 = da as [AnyObject]
                    print("resp is \(da) ")

                }

                    print("respcode count is    \(self.data1.count) ")
                    self.Verticalstackview.height(constant: 40)
                    self.mainView.height(constant: CGFloat(40 * self.data1.count))
                    self.scrollview.height(constant: CGFloat(40 * self.data1.count))

                    for distics in self.data1 {
                    if let resp = distics as? NSDictionary {

                        self.id = resp["id"] as! String
                        self.tiTle = resp["title"] as! String
                        self.releaseYear = resp["releaseYear"] as! String

                        let stackView =  UIStackView()
                        stackView.height(constant: 40)
                        stackView.distribution = .fill
                        stackView.alignment = .fill
                        stackView.axis = .horizontal
                        stackView.spacing = 5

                        let lblId = UILabel()
                        lblId .text = "\(self.id)"
                        lblId .font = UIFont(name: "verdana", size: 15.0)
                        lblId .textAlignment = .center
                        lblId .textColor = .gray
                        lblId .numberOfLines = 0
                        lblId .width(constant: 55)

                        let lbltiTle   = UILabel()
                        lbltiTle.text = "\(self.tiTle)"
                        lbltiTle.font = UIFont(name: "verdana", size: 15.0)
                        lbltiTle.textAlignment = .left
                        lbltiTle.textColor = .black
                        lbltiTle.numberOfLines = 0
                        lbltiTle.width(constant: 120)
                        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target:self,action: #selector(self.tapFunction) )
                        lbltiTle.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        lbltiTle.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
                        self.testtext = lbltiTle.text!

                        let lblRYear = UILabel()
                        lblRYear.text = "\(self.releaseYear)"
                        lblRYear.font = UIFont(name: "verdana", size: 15.0)
                        lblRYear.textAlignment = .right
                        lblRYear.textColor = .black
                        lblRYear.numberOfLines = 0
                        lblRYear.width(constant: 100)

                        stackView.addArrangedSubview(lblId )
                        stackView.addArrangedSubview(lbltiTle)
                        stackView.addArrangedSubview(lblRYear)


                        self.Verticalstackview.addArrangedSubview(stackView)

                    }
                }
            }
            print(self.values1)
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap working")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondcntroller = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    secondcntroller.mystring = self.testtext
}
}
 extension UIView{
func height(constant : CGFloat){
    setConstraint(value: constant,attribute: .height)
}
func width(constant : CGFloat){
    setConstraint(value: constant,attribute: .width)
}
private func removeConstraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute){
    constraints.forEach {
        if $0.firstAttribute == attribute
        {
            removeConstraint($0)
        }
    }
}
private func setConstraint(value:CGFloat ,attribute: NSLayoutAttribute){
    removeConstraint(attribute: attribute)
    let Constraint =
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                           attribute: attribute,
                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                           toItem: nil,
                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: value)
    self.addConstraint(Constraint)
}

}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var mystring = String()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text=mystring
}
}
```

When I click the movie name text, I want that to be displayed on the second view using segue.
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvm8j.png
But always it displays the last movie name. Please assist me sorting this issue.
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqyqM.png

Comment: Who is "mystring" from SecondsViewController? And how did you set it?

Comment: override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondcntroller = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    secondcntroller.mystring = self.testtext
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your tapFunction

```
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchedLabel = sender.view as! UILabel
    self.testtext = touchedLabel.text
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: self)
}
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Now as you wants to pass the multiple values, what you can do is:

First change your for in loop from

```
for distics in self.data1 {
```

To

```
for (index, distics) in self.data1.enumerated() {
```

Now, set the tag to your label below this line

```
lbltiTle.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
// Add tag to your label
lbltiTle.tag = index
//**TIP: You should name the variables in camelCase format**
```

Now modify your function, that detects the tap on label and get the object with index being passed with the label in form of it's tag. Modify it to.

```
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchedLabel = sender.view as! UILabel
    let touchedIndex = touchedLabel.tag
    let selectedDict: NSDictionary = self.data1[touchedIndex]
    print("selectedDict:\(selectedDict)")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: self)
}
```

You can print the required values from it.

NOTE: For the pure swift approach, you should Avoid using NSDictionary, better use [String: Any] which is a key value pair.

Hope it helps

Comment: could you please tell me how to pass **year** along with **movie** name

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer

Answer (score 0):

The self.testtext property from ViewController is not set properly. It should be set every time the tapFunction() is called.
Any way I recomand you to use UITabiewViewController and a data source array which should hold all your elements to display.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

That is because you are passing `testtext` as a parameter to the next `ViewController.mystring`. `testtext` is being changed every time on the loop and the last time it is being changed it is on the last element. Therefore you need to save an index to know where you pressed.

### Solution

Change your for loop to get the index of the element you're iterating as above

```
for index in 0..<self.data1.count {
    let distics = self.data1[index]
        // Other lines of code
        lbltiTle.tag = index
}
```

Change your handler as below

```
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap working")
    guard let index = sender.view?.tag,
        let title = (self.data1[index] as? NSDictionary)["title"] else { return }

    testtext = title
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: *“It hurts having these questions ...”* – you can downvote and/or not answer the question if you feel that the question is bad. As part of an answer, such a remark is not helpful or constructive. See also the (new) [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 0):

Add one more function for your label.

```
lbltiTle.target(forAction: onClickLabel, withSender:)
```

Definition -

```
func onClickLabel(sender: UILabel) {
     self.testtext = sender.text
}
```

Call this in your tap function